# SHLineGraphView - change only first plot color

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph

I am using [SHLineGraphView](https://github.com/grevolution/SHLineGraphView) in my app.
I want to change first plot color with different color.

i tried `kPlotPointFillColorKey` but this is changing color of all plot. i want to change only first plot.

is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

You can change only this attributes:

```
  NSDictionary *_plotThemeAttributes = @{
                                     kPlotFillColorKey : [UIColor colorWithRed:0.47 green:0.75 blue:0.78 alpha:0.5],
                                     kPlotStrokeWidthKey : @2,
                                     kPlotStrokeColorKey : [UIColor colorWithRed:0.18 green:0.36 blue:0.41 alpha:1],
                                     kPlotPointFillColorKey : [UIColor colorWithRed:0.18 green:0.36 blue:0.41 alpha:1],
                                     kPlotPointValueFontKey : [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS" size:18]
                                     };
```

and this:

```
  NSDictionary *_themeAttributes = @{
                                 kXAxisLabelColorKey : [UIColor colorWithRed:0.48 green:0.48 blue:0.49 alpha:0.4],
                                 kXAxisLabelFontKey : [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS" size:10],
                                 kYAxisLabelColorKey : [UIColor colorWithRed:0.48 green:0.48 blue:0.49 alpha:0.4],
                                 kYAxisLabelFontKey : [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS" size:10],
                                 kYAxisLabelSideMarginsKey : @20,
                                 kPlotBackgroundLineColorKey : [UIColor colorWithRed:0.48 green:0.48 blue:0.49 alpha:0.4],
                                 kDotSizeKey : @10
                                 };
```

Comment: yes but i want to change color of only one plot.
it change all plot color from above code.

Comment: This library does not support such operation , try this https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: this library is in swift. i want for objective c

Comment: You can use Swift libraries in your Objective-C application to. Read this documentation: [Apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)